# Can I scrape or extract data inside app.run

Tags: python, json, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm using python and beautifulsoup and i need to extract some data under `app.run({"data":Id":"124330049","stock":83})`. When I tried to find those value it returns an empty list using find.

Can I extract/scrape data inside app.run?

code:

```
 soup = content.find('script').get_text()
      found_data = json.loads(soup)
      print(found_data)
```

// this gives me error: need to output stock: 83

Comment: Can you more elaborate and post code and desired output??

Comment: I should get as output the value of stock with the value of 83 - need to get stock: 83

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your code?

Comment: Where is the code that you've tried?

Comment: better use regular expressions

Comment: i have tried the code below since i can't soup.find('script', type:''} since it was just define('app/pc', ['//laz-g-cdn.alicdn.com/lzdfe/pdp-platform/0.1.11/pc.js'], function(app) {
      try{
          app.run({"data: Id":"124330049","stock":83}).

Answer (score 1):

You could select all the script tags with a specific substring in and then regex out what you want

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<script type="text/javascript">app.run({"data":Id":"124330049","stock":83})</script>
'''
soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
scripts = [script.text for script in soup.select('script') if 'app.run({"data":Id"' in script.text]

r = re.compile(r'"stock":(\d+)}')
for script in scripts:
    print(r.findall(script))
```

Comment: you seem to be a regex fan, but still why not just use (the admittedly somewhat convoluted) `print(scripts[0].split(',')[1].split('}')`?

Comment: @JackFleeting I'm not a fan of regex in web-scraping for two reasons. I am not good at regex and I don't like regex mixed with html though we are dealing with a string here. Was in it for practicing regex and regex with python as I am a python newb. Totally agree with your method.

Comment: I have been following (and using!) your answers for a while, so I find it hard to believe you're a newb at anything... Great job(s)!

Comment: I have exactly extracted the data by using split like - @JackFleeting did.